# Error says class not found

Tags: java

```
public boolean addUser(User user) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        String sql ="INSERT INTO User VALUES ("+0+",'"+user.getName()+"','"+user.getType()+"',AES_ENCRYPT('"+user.getPassword()+"','') ) ";
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
        int res = stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        return res > 0;
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Exception

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

cannot correct my error...
I invoke this method remotely..
I don;t know how to encrypt password like this using java

Comment: `java.rmi.UnmarshalException`! Are you invoking this method remotely using RMI? If so, don't you think you should mention this in your question?

Comment: Yes..Remotely. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the method fails with a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` on the RMI server, and the exception is being sent back, but you don't have the MySQL JDBC driver installed on the RMI client, so it cannot resolve the exception class, and the real error message gets lost, when it is replaced by the `ClassNotFoundException`.

You have a few choices:

- Add the MySQL JDBC driver to the classpath of the RMI client.
  Since the RMI client doesn't need MySQL access, this seems like the wrong solution.
- Catch the exception on the RMI server, and throw a JDK built-in exception, e.g. `SQLSyntaxErrorException`.
  This class will exist on the RMI client, so you can see what the real error is.
- Catch the exception on the RMI server, log the error message in a log file on the server, then throw a totally generic exception, e.g. `RuntimeException("Error adding user. See log file on server")`.
  This will hide RMI server internals from the client, which helps keep the server secure from hackers.